# Delphi: Memory leak when creating a TStringList inside a class

Tags: class, delphi, memory-leaks, tstringlist

I have this pieces of code

```
TSql = class
  private
    FConnString: TStringList;
  public
    property ConnString: TStringList read FConnString write FConnString;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
  end;

var 
  Sql: TSql;

...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TSql.Create;
begin
  //inherited Create;
  FConnString:=TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TSql.Destroy;
begin
  FConnString.Free;
  //inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Sql.Create;
  Sql.ConnString.Add('something');
  showmessage(Sql.ConnString.Text);
  Sql.Destroy;
end;
```

Why when creating the FConnString is creating a memory leak, after a press the button?

..................................
..................................
..................................
..................................

Comment: Let me expand. If you're able to call Sql.Create without errors, you already have a valid instance of your Tsql. When you call Create on it, it creates another FConnString. IOW, remove that line and you'll be fine.

Comment: Surely that should be `Sql := TSql.Create;`?

Comment: yap... my bad. You are wright! it works! anyhow I still have a problem with my real code. I will search more deep. In my original code is with Sql:=TSql.Create but still have problems.

Comment: I rolled the question back. It's no fun taking aim at a moving target.

Comment: That global variable  makes me feel ill

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### EDIT The actual problem

The original code in the question was as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Sql.Create;
  Sql.ConnString.Add('something');
  showmessage(Sql.ConnString.Text);
  Sql.Destroy;
end;
```

The problem line was `Sql.Create;` which should have been `Sql := TSql.Create;`. The reason this causes a memory leak is as follows:

- `Sql.Create;` is called from a **nil** reference.
- This calls `TStringList.Create;` and attempts to assigned the result to `FConnString`.
- Because Sql is a nil reference, this triggers an Access Violation.
- The problem is there is no way to destroy the `TStringList` instance that was created.

### Additional problems in original answer

Your destructor is virtual, you're not overriding.
You're not calling your inherited Destructor.

```
TSql = class
  private
    FConnString: TStringList;
  public
    property ConnString: TStringList read FConnString write FConnString;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override; //Correction #1
  end;

destructor TSql.Destroy;
begin
  FConnString.Free;
  inherited Destroy; //Correction #2
end;
```

---

#### EDIT

A few general tips:

1. I applaud you for using composition (making `FConnString` a member instead of inheriting from `TStringList`). However, by exposing it publicly, you would lose many of the benefits. Specifically you would be exposed to [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violations. I'm not saying never do it. But be aware that you can create a maintenance problem down the line if a large amount of client code accesses `ConnString` directly.
2. Declaring `FConnString: TStringList;` violates the principle of [Program to an interface, not an implementation](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation/). `TStringList` is a specific implementation of `TStrings` and this declaration prevents use of other subclasses of `TStrings`. This is more of a problem combined with #1: if in a few years time you find and want to switch to a different/better subclass implementation of `TStrings` client code that is binding to `TStringList` now creates much more work and risk. Basically the preferred aproach can be summed up as:

   - Declare the variable as the abtract base type.
   - Create the instance as the specifically chosen implementation subclass.
   - Let polymorphism ensure subclass behaviour is applied correctly in overridden methods.

Again this is a general guideline. If you specifically need access to properties/methods that were added at the `TStringList` level of the hierarchy, then you have to bind to that class. But if you don't need it, don't do it.

Comment: The destructor is already virtual, in `TObject`. You need to declare is as `override` instead.

Comment: Correction #2 wouldn't fix a leak, TObject.Destroy does nothing. So same goes for #1.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Correct, they are additional problems. I've updated with an explanation of the actual memory leak.

Comment: @Craig - Thanks. I'm sure this is not the issue though, as the AV would be mentioned in the question. The issue is, the question is bogus.

Comment: Well described answer. Except the mistake, some more things I have learned anyhow from your detailed answer. Thank you @CraigYoung!

Comment: Also, an important thing mentioned Allen in [`his answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23917449/960757). In the original code, the property field can be overwritten by an assigned string list which leads to a leak of the instance created in constructor.

Answer (score 11):

There are two things I see. The first of which was already covered by the other comments and answer regarding the lack of "override" on the destructor.

The second issue is the property declaration itself. In general, you should never declare a property that references an object field in the "write" clause. The reason is that assigning to that property will "leak" the existing instance in that field. Use a method for the "write" clause of the property declaration:

```
property ConnString: TStringList read FConnString write SetConnString;
...
procedure TSql.SetConnString(Value: TStringList);
begin
  FConnString.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Also notice that this method does not overwrite the FConnString field either. It merely copies the "value" or the "content" of the Value TStringList into the FConnString instance. In this manner the TSql instance is in complete and total control over the lifetime of that field. It is the responsibility of the code assigning that property to control the lifetime of the Value TStringlist.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare `Destroy()` with the `override` specifier, so `TSql.Destroy` is not actually being called when the object is destroyed.

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

Comment: Not being called? He is calling Tsql.Destroy.

Comment: Whilst he should override `Destroy`, in this case the code calls `Destroy` directly and so this issue does not address the true issue.

Answer (score 0):

The object is not created correctly. It must be:

```
Sql:=TSql.Create;
```

From here is coming the memory leak.

Comment: No, what would come from there is an AV.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I upvoted your comment, then realised the error actually **was** responsible for leaking memory (see my updated answer). (Alas I cannot remove the upvote on the comment.)

Comment: @Craig - I don't think there's anything wrong with my comment. The asker surely does not have an AV, otherwise he would have it in his question.